# What does flag&0xffffffff do in this example

Tags: c

Trying to convert a C program over to Javascript as I have found old source code. The only thing is I'm kind of learning C as I go, but the hardest thing about being fresh to a language is you don't exactly know which terms to google. Anyways,

I have this bit of code:

```
unsigned long long flag=0;

if (class[1]=='W') flag|=CF_WARRIOR;
else flag|=CF_MAGE;
```

In a header file it says

```
#define CF_WARRIOR (1ull<<16)
```

Then the last part of it is:

```
(unsigned int)(flag&0xffffffff) // Assuming some sort of type casting followed by a bitwise &?
```

Just not sure what the programmer was trying to accomplish at the time.

Sorry for the poor question, but I don't exactly know what to google to figure this one out, I understand `1ull` is 1 unsigned long long and `<< 16` is a bitwise shift. But not sure what `|=` is doing or `flag&0xffffffff`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a way to reject the uppermost 32 bits.

Type of `flag` is `unsigned long long` and it appears only lower `32` bits are used in the implementation.

For more details you can read [bitwise and operator in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.22.26.22)

Comment: What is the `|=` doing in flag|=CF_MAGE?

Comment: Check the same page, `|` is used to set some bits and `&` is used to reset specific bits to 0.

Comment: @Mohit Jain, in my opinion your statement is not completely correct. This construction `(unsigned int)(flag&0xffffffff)` does not change (does not zero) the bits of `flag` by itself because this is only a read operation, not write operation. However, if the result of this operation is assigned back to `flags` (not given by the topic starter), then yes, due to the added write operation it will result into zeroing the higher bits as you wrote. In the read context (i.e. within `if`) as it is, this construction will test whether any of the lower bits is set.

Comment: @dmi I never said we are zeroing upper (32+) bits of  `flag`.

Comment: That's why I propose to change the first statement of your comment :). Otherwise the statement `a way to zero smth.` sounds like to set to zero smth. what is the write operation as I described.